# Use of bind when calling a function on onClick Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following is the sample code I was working on.

So basically there are two hyperlinks lets say , A and B.

I wanted when you click A, I want to console log 'You selected A', and if you select B, console log 'You selected B'.

I am confused as to why do I need to pass the parameters using bind ?

**In the snippet below, console.log occurs when you click MIT but not when you click Stanford**

'You clicked Stanford' is console logged as soon as I run the program and nothing happens on clicking it afterwards.
'You Clicked MIT' works perfectly on the other hand.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class ToppersView extends Component {

  state = {
        currentSelected : 'Harvard'
  }  

  handleClick (str) {

    console.log(" You selected ",str)
  }

  render () {

      return (
         <div className = 'container'>
            <h3> University is : {this.state.currentSelected}</h3>
             <div>
              {/* Works */}
              <a onClick = {this.handleClick.bind(null,"MIT")}>#MIT</a>

              {/*Does not  work */}
              <a onClick ={this.handleClick("Stanford")}>#Stanford</a>

            </div>
            <br/> 


        </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: one returns a function, one returns nothing. onclick wants a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.handleClick("Stanford")` calls the function right here, while `this.handleClick.bind(null,"MIT")` binds the context and argument and returns the function so it can be called later.

An event listener needs a reference to a function, but your `handleClick` method doesn't return anything, so after it's been executed there's nothing to bind to event listener. You could modify the `handleClick` method to return another function which would be called on click:

```
handleClick (str) {
   return function(){ // this function will be used as event callback
    console.log(" You selected ",str)
   }
}
// the function will be executed and the returned function called in event callback
<a onclick ={this.handleClick("Stanford")}>#Stanford</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. What you are doing `onclick = {this.handleClick("Stanford")}` just calls the method immediately and returns `undefined`. What you want to do is pass a reference of your function, not call the function. Also `bind` does provide a reference of your function, but it does (and is meant) for more than that. You can just reference your function without the `()` in it. See #2.
2. What you aren't doing (but maybe others who come here are doing or for those who are curious), but also isn't a good idea `onClick ={this.handleClick}` because you won't be able to access `this` once inside your event handler. Although by doing it this way, it does now set an eventhandler function. However, when that function runs, any references to `this` will be null (eg: as you are in reactjs, you won't be able to do useful things like `this.setState({...});` **Although, your code will work now so there is no need for `bind` to make it work.**
3. What (probably) you need to do, and why `this.handleClick.bind(this)` because of [how this binding works in Javscript](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/objects-classes/ch2.md) and also there isn't much value in putting hard-strings inside your callback function. If you want to reference it, do it dynamically like this `e.target.innerText` see the codepen for a complete and re-worked example: https://codepen.io/Zombies333/pen/yLLrLyx

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo and a missing .bind here:

```
<a onclick ={this.handleClick("Stanford")}>#Stanford</a>
```

This is correct:

```
<a onClick ={this.handleClick.bind(null, "Stanford")}>#Stanford</a>
```

If you dont want to use .bind you can use arrow functions. So instead of:

```
handleClick (str) {

    console.log(" You selected ",str)
}
```

Use:

```
handleClick = (str) => {

    console.log(" You selected ",str)
 }
```